# Admin Dashboard - Unexpected token } in JSON at position 33

Tags: javascript, admin-panel, magento2.2.6, adminnotification

I know there are many questions here about the *unexpected token in JSON* error but nothing seems to apply in my case.
In my case I log into the admin backend and get this error:
[image: error message]
I managed to find the part which causes the error in the source code (Source page in browser):

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright &copy; Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap" data-bind="scope: 'notification_area.notification_area'">
    <div data-role="spinner" data-component="notification_area.notification_area.columns"
         class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">
        <div class="spinner">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": }}</script>
</div>
```

I as well managed to figure out that it is inside the `notifications` container but I do not know which block causes the error. And I don't know which template is responsible for the code.

Anyone knows which block generates this code or which template contains it?

I already did the following:

- cleared cache
- removed static content
- static content deploy
- removed vendor and did a `composer install`
- removed generated code

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Debug entry point: \Magento\Ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent::_toHtml

Comment: As per logs there is error in scripts.js file at either line number 117 or 87. keep `debugger`  in that lines

Comment: \Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::appendLayoutConfiguration seems to generated json which cannot be encoded

Comment: in 2.3 this would throw an exception: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Result.php#L94 because JsonSerializer is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::appendLayoutConfiguration` calls
`\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Structure::generate` and that produces wrong invalid json.

`json_last_error_msg()` gives following message:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Debugging further and into `\Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::appendLayoutConfiguration` showed wrong encoded characters:
[image: wrong encoding]

There is no check if if the json is valid. In 2.3 it would throw an error.

Removing the wrong notification from `admin_system_messages` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass at least empty value for **"Magento_Ui/js/core/app"** either change the content or remove following line.`<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": }}</script>`
finally output will be `<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app":"" }}</script>`

Comment: problem is the error comes from core files so I cannot simple remove something